# SQL Server function does not work as I expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I got a SQL Server function. When I use as query command, it works fine, but when I put in a function, it does not work every time.

Here is my function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ConvertToFloat
    (@number_str nvarchar)
RETURNS float
AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@number_str, '$', ''), '%',''),',','') AS float);
END
```

Example:

```
select dbo.AmazonNumberStrToFloat('1234.12') // return 1
```

but when I select

```
cast(replace(replace(replace('$1,123.45', '$', ''), '%',''),',','') as float) // return 1123.45
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should ***NEVER EVER*** define a SQL Server variable or parameter as `varchar` or `nvarchar` ***WITHOUT*** providing an explicit length!

If you omit the length - it will default to **exactly 1 character** - which usually isn't what you want or expect.

So replace this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ConvertToFloat
    (@number_str nvarchar)
```

with something more sensible like

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ConvertToFloat
    (@number_str NVARCHAR(25) )
```

or whatever length makes sense here, for you - but you **MUST PROVIDE** a length!